# I want to change scale of visualViewport. How can I achieve this pragmatically?

Tags: html, viewport

I want to change scale of `visualViewport`. I want to control zoom pragmatically on certain condition. How can I achieve this?

Edit: The window.visualViewport.scale is totally different from the zoom of the CSS transforms which was previously referred as a solution to this problem and as a reason for locking this question. CSS transforms operate inside the layout viewport while visualViewport scale does not affect the layout per design.

Comment: Btw. I have an answer to this if this question were to be reopened.

Comment: Refusal to reopen just shows the incompetence of the user base of this site.

Comment: This question should really not mark as duplicate! It is a very good question.

Comment: @loop Could you please provide some tips here?

Comment: @nuynait I will if you create a new question because "this question has been answered, is not unique, and doesn’t differentiate itself from another question."

Answer (score 0):

This i believe from what I've researched and read will need an API.
I have found some code on the subject and a link to where you can understand how this API works. I think if I understand your question, this will be a solution:

```
let pendingUpdate = false;

function viewportHandler() {
  if (pendingUpdate) return;
  pendingUpdate = true;

  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    pendingUpdate = false;
    var layoutViewport = document.getElementById('layoutViewport');

    // Since the bar is position: fixed we need to offset it by the
    // visual viewport's offset from the layout viewport origin.
    var offsetLeft = viewport.offsetLeft;
    var offsetTop = viewport.height
                - layoutViewport.getBoundingClientRect().height
                + viewport.offsetTop;

    // You could also do this by setting style.left and style.top if you
    // use width: 100% instead.
    bottomBar.style.transform = 'translate(' +
                                offsetLeft + 'px,' +
                                offsetTop + 'px) ' +
                                'scale(' + 1/viewport.scale + ')'
    }
}

window.visualViewport.addEventListener('scroll', viewportHandler);
window.visualViewport.addEventListener('resize', viewportHandler);
```

Check it out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Visual_Viewport_API

Comment: This is event handler which will get fire on scale change. I want to change the scale by code.\

Comment: I understand, check my revised answer. This may be a little more suited to your needs.